# Waterproof putty for Azek lumber

Tags: waterproofing, trim, putty

What can I use as waterproof putty for Azek lumber, exterior application? I am looking to mainly plug and cover (hopefully invisible) screw/nail wholes in Azek brick moulding, the same way I would use wood putty for in interior jobs on real lumber, like door and window trim, baseboard etc.

I have seen people water-sortof-proof using Quad door/window caulking but that's hard to get smooth. Is there a waterproof variant of regular indoor wood putty? Maybe epoxy of some sort?

Comment: sounds like Azek is a brand name ... talk to the manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

They have a filler for finish nail holes.

I’m not sure how it would do for countersunk screws.

[image: azek nail filler]

￼

Answer (score 1):

I use an epoxy filler I have around for repairing wood rot.  You could probably use regular Bondo or equivalent.   My siding contractor face nailed all the Azek corner and trim boards, so I ended up epoxy filling all of the holes, sanding smooth, and painting the entire boards white.  (with a roller)

Painting composite trim actually causes it to shed water and dirt better than the "plain" factory finish.